# Custom exception, Javadoc unknown throwable exception

Tags: java, javadoc

I have trouble with generating Javadoc, it complains

"Uknown throwable @throws pl.sydygaliev.java_journey.model.exception.WrongFormatException"

Here's the body of javadoc comment

```
/**
 * The method that is used to handle given keyword.
 * If keyword has illegal values, it returns null.
 * @param keyword is used for keyword validation
 * @return keyword with given value or null if keyword
 * has unacceptable characters
 * @throws WrongFormatException when there is unacceptable 
 * character for the keyword
 */
public String handleKeyword(String keyword) {
```

Javadoc
Body of the custom exception

```
package pl.sydygaliev.java_journey.model.exception;


public class WrongFormatException extends Exception{
}
```

InitialHandlerAndStorer class where javadoc trouble occured and subpackage of custom exceptions within that package
[image: InitialHandlerAndStorer class where javadoc trouble occured]

Comment: Does your class include an import of the exception? Otherwise you have to fully classify it. If you dont know what I mean, please share the full code of the `InitialHandlerAndStorer` file.

Comment: Yessir, I have it imported, and the exception is recognized within the code but somehow not  by the javadoc

Comment: Does it work for javadoc when you fully qualify it? I.e. `@throws pl.sydygaliev.java_journey.model.exception.WrongFormatException when there is unacceptable character for the keyword`?

Comment: How do you run the javadoc command? Maybe it is missing the file in its classpath arguments etc

Comment: Javadoc works fine, I generate it in netbeans, in the run section. If I remove throws tag, javadoc is generated without problems

Comment: I tried to fully qualify and it still has the same error complain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the method must have the following syntax:

```
public String handleKeyword(String keyword) throws WrongFormatException{
...
```

But since I had try and catch block within the function I couldn't create the above syntax. I removed try and catch block in the method and added the try and catch block elsewhere, where method was called